# Java Arraylist two different columns

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, items

I have an array list with the name and cost of an item, however, I'd like to separate the two, especially so that I can sum the values of the costs.

heres what I have so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class henrys {

    public static ArrayList<String> products = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        products.add("Calvin Klein Blue Shorts, Size: Medium, $45");
        products.add("Ralph Lauren Blue Shirt, Size: Large, $50");
        products.add("Gap Beige Khakis, Size: 30, $20");
        products.add("Calvin Klein Black Shirt, Size: Medium, $35");
        products.add("USA Jersey White, Size: Medium, $100");
        System.out.println((products)); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you a considered a `Map`?

Comment: use ArrayList<Hashmap> instead

Comment: @Bharath Or a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

Comment: Don't represent a Product as a string; create a Product class with all of the various properties you need, with the appropriate types.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes he wants to maintain the order, he could use LinkedHashMap.

Answer (score 3):

Creating an ArrayList like this really doesn't make sense, and goes completely against the purpose of a language centered around objects.

Create a Product class, give it a `name`, `price`, and `size` field, and then create an ArrayList of Product objects.

To get the sum of the prices, you could iterate over every `Product` in the `ArrayList` and add its price:

Sidenote: Storing monetary values as a double is horrible idea. I only did it to show you how to get started.

**FINAL EDIT**

You need to create a class called `Product` with the following code:

```
public class Product {

    public String name, size;
    public double price;

    public Product(String name, String size, double price){
        this.name = name;
        this.size = size;
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

In your `Main` Class:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    products.add(new Product("Shorts", "Small", 5.45);
    products.add(new Product("Shirt", "Large", 15.15);
    products.add(new Product("Hat", "Small", 10.25);

    //Calculate total price.
    double price = 0.00;
    for(Product p : products){
        price += p.price;
    }
    System.out.println("Total cost: " + price);

}
```

Comment: in that way would it be easy to sum the prices?

Comment: @JoeBoyle how would I add an object if I used this format?

Comment: Why "Storing monetary values as a double is horrible idea" ?

Comment: @ismailyavuz Double and Float datatypes are floating point. Floating point values encounter "round-off" errors. For example, doing 1.03 - .42 would return 0.6100000000000001. For more on why we don't use floating point datatypes for currency, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Comment: i inputted this and when I play it I get no result

Comment: @user3788811 I'd need to see your code. Any errors?

Comment: @user3788811 I'll create a final edit with all of the code in one place.

Comment: @user3788811 I have made a final edit. If you need further help with basic OOP principles, I'd suggest Google'ing some Java tutorials.